# How to get RSS support for org-mode files

Tags: emacs, rss, org-mode

I have created a static blog and use org-publish-project to publish org-mode files to HTML. Now I want to generate RSS automatically, Is there any elisp packages which have this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `ox-rss.el` in the `contrib/lisp` in standard Org-Mode package (since version 8.0) - you may need to install it manually or via `el-get`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,this package seems buggy and unstable and org-mode 8.0 has too many incompatible changes which will break my configuration. so I want to use org-mode 7.9. Now I have written a python script to get rss.....